# How to pass value from req.render() to ejs , then from that ejs to another

Tags: node.js, ejs, render

---

### server.js

```
app
  .route("/")
  .get((req, res) => {
    res.render("home", { tofirstejs: usercount });
  })
```

---

### home.ejs

```
<%- include('partials/header.ejs', {tolastejs:tofirstejs}); -%>
<%- include('partials/signin.ejs'); -%>
<%- include('partials/footer.ejs'); -%>
```

---

### header.ejs

```
<body>
  <div id="alert"></div>
  <h3>  <%= tolastejs%> user</h3>  //want inital value of usercount here
</body>
```

---

I want to know how to pass value through multiple ejs. I can solve this issue by reducing the middle ejs and calling the final one directly, But my intention is learning. So if there is any way to implement this. PLEASE DO LET ME KNOW.

Comment: Your code shows `res.render('home')`, but you don't show `home.ejs`.  You also show `first.ejs` and `last.ejs`, but no way that either one of them is rendered and no connection between either of them.  We can't follow the code flow here to see what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: You don't pass data through multiple `.ejs` files that are not rendered as part of the same rendering.  To do something like that, you'd probably have to use a session and put the data in the session and then get it from the session to pass it to the other renders.

Comment: @jfriend00 Sorry for that, Actually first = home and last = header ejs files. that was a mistake from my side.

Okay, So if that's the case. then I will call the header directly. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you actually don't need to write it again, i would add a extra step for error handling

```
app.get('/', (req, res , next) => {

res.render('home',{tofirstejs: usercount},  (error, html) =>{
if(error){ 
 console.log(error) 
 next(error)
 return
 }

  res.send(html)   
 })
})
```

in the view file

```
<%- include('partials/header.ejs') %>
<%- include('partials/signin.ejs'); %>
<%- include('partials/footer.ejs'); %>
```

`tofirstejs` can be used in all 3 partials